# Getting this Error : -" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for". When I use Hibernate Config for reverse eng. my DB

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate

I'm trying to reverse Engeneer my simple MYSQL DB using Hibernate Configuration with eclipse IDE.But getting below error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/client1_db
```

I went through similar issues. This is a Marven Web Project and I can see the MYSQL_connector_java_5.1.34.jar is there under Marven Dependencies library. Some had suggested "No suitable driver found" means the drivers are loading but an issue with the DB connection. I have tried to connect to the localhost and the DB was created using MySQL workbench and it is accessible. I even tried using myphp admin and the DB is accessible.

hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookshop</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop the existing tables and create new one -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Then I tried using different server port 3307 as below. Still the same error.

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/client1_db</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
```

The full Error Message

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/client1_db
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.AbstractMetaDataDialect.getConnection(AbstractMetaDataDialect.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.AbstractMetaDataDialect.getMetaData(AbstractMetaDataDialect.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.AbstractMetaDataDialect.caseForSearch(AbstractMetaDataDialect.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.JDBCMetaDataDialect.getTables(JDBCMetaDataDialect.java:22)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.processTables(JDBCReader.java:476)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCReader.java:74)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractJDBCReaderFacade.readDatabaseSchema(AbstractJDBCReaderFacade.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.readDatabaseSchema(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Hibernate Configuration screenshot

[image]

Package Explore

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing the reverse engineering directly I first added the Database to the Eclipse providing JDBC driver path. After testing the connection was successful then performed the reverse engineering and it was successful.

Steps >
01. Go to Data Source Explore 
[image]

2. Add the DB connection

[image]

3. Make sure you map the JDBC drivers

[image]

[image]

[image]

04.Test at the end. Make sure your server is running..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the below page :

https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/09/javasqlsqlexception-no-suitable-driver-mysql-jdbc-localhost.html